# How to supress loops in a digraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, manipulate

I have the following `Code` working nicely (Part of this code has been developed by users in this forum).

```
Clear[vLabels, selectAbove, subgraphAbove];
mm = RandomReal[0.5, {10, 10}];
vLabels = {1 -> AGR, 2 -> FIS, 3 -> CO1, 4 -> CO2, 5 -> MA1, 6 -> MA2,
7 -> EGW, 8 -> CST, 9 -> WHS, 10 -> HOT};

selectAbove[\[Theta]_] := BoolEval[\[Theta] < mm];
subgraphAbove[\[Theta]_] := AdjacencyGraph[selectAbove[\[Theta]],
PlotLabel -> \[Theta] < Subscript[m, ij], VertexSize -> 0.3, 
VertexLabels -> vLabels , ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 150];
Manipulate[
subgraphAbove[\[Theta]], {{\[Theta], 0.001, "Threshold \[Theta] <"}, 
0, 0.5, 0.01}]
```

I simply do not want to see the loops in this digraph. I looked for a command to suppress the loops, but to my surprise no single command exists. Or I could find it in my search.

I will appreciate if you suggest me a way to suppress the loops.

- **EDIT 1**

I face a puzzle here. The `Code` given above simply counts the number of edges in an interval `theta1` and `theta2`. If I keep the maximum range to find the maximum number of edges in the entire graph, it gives me a `puzzling` result. To see the puzzle, let us just look at the following three maps.

The first graph indicates that in the range given, the number of linkages or edges is 136. (Keep in mind that histogram is giving the right and consistent answer.)

[image]

The second graph indicates that in the range given, the number of linkages or edges is 271, which is correct. (Keep in mind that histogram is giving the right and consistent answer again.)

The puzzle is that, although I reduce the range, expecting that I will get a smaller number of edges compared to the range covering the entire graph, I receive a larger number that 136.

Can somebody tell me what I am missing here or `Mathematica` is doing something that I cannot see. The additional puzzle is that Histogram always gives the correct number (I checked it through almost all ranges.) but a simple command `EdgeCount` does not behave in the expected manner.

See the following full `Code` to replicate the situation, where the `mm` matrix is large and hence you may check it with random numbers between 0-0.5:

```
Clear[selectBetween, subgraphBetween];
selectBetween[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
BoolEval[\[Theta]1 <= mm <= \[Theta]2];
subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_] := 
AdjacencyGraph[selectBetween[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2],
PlotLabel -> \[Theta]1 <= Subscript[m, ij] <= \[Theta]2, 
VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabels -> vLabels , ImagePadding -> 20, 
ImageSize -> 150];
Manipulate[Grid[{
{"Digraph within the range for " <> 
  ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm], 
 "Total number of edges in the interval", 
 "Histogram"}, {subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2], 
 EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2]], 
 Histogram[{0}, {binlims = 
    Range[\[Theta]1, \[Theta]2, (\[Theta]2 - \[Theta]1)/
      nbars]}, (EdgeCount[subgraphBetween[##]] & @@@ 
     Partition[binlims, 2, 1] &), LabelingFunction -> Above]}} // 
Transpose
],
{{\[Theta]1, 0.00001, 
"Threshold \[Theta]1 < " <> 
ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm]}, 0.00001, 0.5, 
0.005}, {{\[Theta]2, 0.0001, 
ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm] <> 
" < Threshold \[Theta]2"}, \[Theta]1 + 0.00001, 0.5, 0.005},
{{nbars, 10}, 1, 100, 1}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Extract the AdjacencyMatrix and set the diagonal entries to $0$ then plot a new graph with the edited AdjacencyMatrix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`SimpleGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SimpleGraph.html):

> SimpleGraph[g] *removes all self-loops and multiple edges between the same vertices*.

```
Manipulate[SimpleGraph[g = subgraphAbove[θ], ImageSize -> Medium, Options[g]], 
 {{θ, 0.001, "Threshold θ <"}, 0, 0.5, 0.01}, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but somehow it removes the vertex names from the graph. I like to preserve the vertex names if possible.

Comment: @Tugrul, you can use `SimpleGraph[g = subgraphAbove[\[Theta]], Options[g]]` to retain the options of `subgraphAbove[\[Theta]]` in `SimpleGraph`.

Comment: Yes, finally, I got it and it works in the way I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Beware that just transferring `Options[graph]` is not a robust solution. It won't work if the graph has edge properties (e.g. edge weights) as some edges are removed.

Comment: For your case the best solution is to zero out the diagonal of the matrix before creating the graph (I updated my answer)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for your warning. Can we assume that in a simple graph with diagonal elements remaining as they are, `Options[g]` will give me the right result, one that does not drop any edges or change any other properties of the original graph?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Your warning led me to find a puzzle in my `Code` and I cannot find the answer to the puzzle. Maybe you have a suggestion for correcting it.

Answer (score 6):

As others said, [`SimpleGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SimpleGraph.html) will remove both loops and multi-edges. Often this is all you need.  If you need to control the removal of loops and multi-edges separately, you can use `IGSimpleGraph` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

Create a graph.

```
g = IGShorthand["1->2->3->1->2->2->1", 
      MultiEdges -> True, SelfLoops -> True]
```

[image]

Make the graph simple.

```
IGSimpleGraph[g]
```

[image]

Preserve self-loops, but not parallel edges.

```
IGSimpleGraph[g, SelfLoops -> True]
```

[image]

```
IGSimpleGraph[g, MultiEdges -> True]
```

Preserve parallel edges but not self-loops.

[image]

---

`IGSimpleGraph` does not currently preserve graph properties such as egde weights (`SimpleGraph` does, but only in M12.0+). IGraph/M also provides `IGWeightedSimpleGraph` which takes the same options, but preserves edge weights, the most commonly needed edge property.

---

You could also use `EdgeDelete` to remove self-loops. In a directed graph, use

```
EdgeDelete[g, x_ \[DirectedEdge] x_]
```

In M11.3 and earlier, `EdgeDelete` was buggy and would often break the graph if it had properties (styling also counts as properties). In M12.0 it is finally fixed, therefore I can finally recommend it (for M12.0+ only!)

---

Another option, which is specific to your setup, is to remove the diagonal of the adjacency matrix before using `AdjacencyGraph`. You can do this using `IGZeroDiagonal[matrix]` (which is also part of IGraph/M).

---

Finally, if you have an already constructed graph with properties (such as vertex labels), you need to preserve the properties, and you have Mathematica 11.3 or earlier, then you can use `IGTakeSubgraph`.

```
sg = subgraphAbove[.23];

IGTakeSubgraph[sg, DeleteCases[EdgeList[sg], x_ \[DirectedEdge] x_]]
```

[image]

The second argument of `IGTakeSubgraph` can be a set of edges, or a graph. It will keep only those edges from the input graph (the first argument). `IGTakeSubgraph` is quite slow, but it's the most convenient way to take a subgraph and preserve properties in Mathematica 11.3 and earlier. In Mathematica 12.0 and later, the built-in `Subgraph`, `VertexDelete` and `EdgeDelete` already preserve properties.

Comment: It works but `IGSimpleGraph` remove the vertex names also. `SimpleGraph` removes the names too. I like to keep them as they are if possible.

Comment: @TugrulTemel `SimpleGraph` does not remove them in Mathematica 12.0 (finally!!)

Comment: I have `Math 11`. @klrg suggested a solution for this issue. I want to thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

```
myGraph = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 2}]
```

[image]

```
fixedMatrix = 
 Table[If[i == j, 0, AdjacencyMatrix[myGraph][[i, j]]], 
   {i, 1, 3}, 
   {j, 1, 3}];

AdjacencyGraph[fixedMatrix]
```

[image]

Could also use:

```
fixedMatrix = 
 ReplacePart[AdjacencyMatrix[myGraph], Table[{i, i} -> 0, {i, 1, 3}]]
```

Or

```
SimpleGraph[myGraph]
```